# A simple geometry problem with points

Tags: geometry

Given the points $M(3,4)$ and $N(1,2)$, find $x$ in the point $P(x,0)$ so that $PM + PN$ is a minimum.

Comment: What are $M,N$ and $P$?

Comment: They are points in a xoy system

Comment: Hint: Reflect $N$ across the $x$-axis, and call it $N'$. Note that $PN = PN'$. Which $P$ should you take to minimize $MP + PN'$?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't use calculus. Consider the line segments $PM$ and $PN$. Now reflect the line segment $PM$ about the $x$-axis. Observe that the value of $PM+PN$ does not change, regardless of the point $P$ chosen. Thus, we have legally reduced your problem to this simpler one:

> Given the points $M(3,-4)$ and $N(1,2)$, find $x$ in the point $P(x,0)$ such that $PM+PN$ is a minimum.

Now that $M$ and $N$ are on opposite sides of the $x$-axis, it should be clear that the shortest distance between them is a straight line! That is, we must choose $x$ such that $P(x,0)$ is a point on the line $MN$. To do this, it suffices to choose $x$ such that the slope of $PM$ is the same as the slope of $PN$:
$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{x-3}{0-(-4)} &= \frac{x-1}{0-2} \\
\frac{x-3}{4} &= \frac{x-1}{-2} \\
-2(x-3) &= 4(x-1) \\
(x-3) &= -2(x-1) \\
x-3 &= -2x+2 \\
3x &= 5 \\
x&=5/3
\end{align*}$$